# Centrar ventana popup con windows.open

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de para colocar una ventana popup utilizando el metodo de window.open, pero creo que estoy realizando mal el calculo y la ventana me aparece un poco mas hacia la derecha.

En concreto, seria que la ventana quedara justo en el medio con 1/4 del tamaño de la pantalla, esta seria la pagina numero 2, la cual tengo en un html externo.

```
// obtenemos el tamaño dinamico y lo divimos en 4, obteniendo 1/4 de la panatalla.
        var height = (parseInt(window.innerHeight) /4);
        var width =  (parseInt(window.innerWidth) /4);
        // calculo de la ventana
        var x=(screen.width/2)-(width/2);
        //Ajustar verticalmente
        var y=(screen.height/2)-(height/2);
        // definimos una variable
        var v1;
        // inicializamos un función de apertura de la ventana
        function abrirVentana() {
            v1 = window.open('pagina2.html', 'PopUp',
                'scrollbars=yes ' +
                'width=' + width + ' ' +
                'height=' + height + ' ' +
                'top=' + (window.screenTop + (y - (height / 2))) + ' ' +
                'left=' + (window.screenLeft + (x- (width / 2)))
            )
        
            v1.document.write('<h1>Apertura de la pagina 2<h1>');
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = "pagina3.html";
                v1.close();
            }, 3000);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de desarrollar la solución, piensa en el algoritmo, ¿Qué necesitas?

**Requisito:** Que la ventana mida 1/4 de la pantalla (o la ventana padre)
**Solución:** tamaño de ventana padre / 4

**Requisito:** Que la nueva ventana quede centrada
**Solución:** La suma de márgenes externos iguales más ancho de ventana debe ser igual al ancho total de pantalla (o ventana padre)

- Ancho de ventana = Ancho de pantalla / 4
- Espacio disponible = Ancho de pantalla - Ancho de ventana
- Márgenes izquierdo y derecho = Espacio disponible / 2
- Aplicar misma fórmula para márgenes verticales

Conviene hacerlo primero en "papel":

```
// Suponiendo que la pantalla mide 1024 x 768
width = 1024 / 4 // 256
height = 768 / 4 // 192

// Calcular ancho disponible (Ancho de pantalla - ancho de ventana)
a = 1024 - width // 768 
// Calcular márgenes horizontales (posición horizontal de la ventana)
x = a / 2 // 384
// 384 margen izquierdo + 256 ancho de ventana + 384 margen derecho = 1024
// En un solo paso: x = (1024 - width) / 2

// Calcular altura disponible
b = 768 / height // 576
// Calcular márgenes verticales (posición vertical de la ventana)
y = b / 2  // 288
// 288 margen superior + 192 alto de ventana + 288 margen inferior = 768
// En un solo paso: y = (768 - height) / 2
```

Ya está el algoritmo, ahora hay que programarlo:

```
    // Obtenemos el tamaño dinamico y lo divimos en 4, obteniendo 1/4 de la panatalla.
    var height = (parseInt(window.innerHeight) / 4);
    var width = (parseInt(window.innerWidth) / 4);

    // Ajuste horizontal
    var x = parseInt((screen.width - width) / 2);
    // Ajustae vertical
    var y = parseInt((screen.height - height) / 2);
    // Variable para la nueva ventana
    var v1;
    // inicializamos un función de apertura de la ventana
    function abrirVentana() {
        // No es necesario realizar más cálculos
        // Basta con incluir las variables donde corresponde
        v1 = window.open('pagina2.html', 'PopUp',
            `scrollbars=yes
            width=${width}
            height=${height}
            top=${y}
            left=${x}`
        );
    
        v1.document.write('<h1>Apertura de la pagina 2<h1>');
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = "pagina3.html";
            v1.close();
        }, 3000);
    }
```

**Nota:** En lugar de concatenar las opciones, puedes usar [plantillas de cadena de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para facilitar la lectura del código.